# Haskell: Using quickCheckAll with a size constraint (e.g. quickCheckWith (stdArgs {maxSize = n}))

Tags: haskell, quickcheck

I want to be able to use quickCheckAll to run a number of tests together.  At the same time, I need to specify size constraints on my tests.

In the following program, there are two tests that are impractical without size constraints.  Getting all the partitions of a very large integer is beyond the computational power of this algorithm, and testing a random list of strictly positive integers would require too many lists to be discarded.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
module Partitions where

import Test.QuickCheck
import Test.QuickCheck.All
import Data.List (sort)

sizeCheck n = quickCheckWith (stdArgs {maxSize = n})

partitions :: Int -> [[Int]]
partitions 0 = [[]]
partitions n | n > 0
     = [k:xs | k <- [1..n], xs <- partitions (n - k), all (k <=) xs]

-- "adding up all of the numbers in each partition should give "
prop_partitions :: Int -> Property
prop_partitions n =
  n >= 0 ==> all ((== n) . sum) (partitions n)

-- "sorting any list of strictly positive integers gives one of the
--  partitions of its sum"
prop_partitions' :: [Int] -> Property
prop_partitions' xs =
  all (>0) xs ==> sort xs `elem` partitions (sum xs)

return []
runTests = $quickCheckAll
```

Normally I will use `quickCheckAll` to run all the tests using the pragma `{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}`, naming all the tests of type `Property` to start with `prop_`, concluding the program with `return []` and `runTests = $quickCheckAll`, then running `runTests`.

The textbook that I am using gives a convenient way to specify size constraints with `quickCheckWith`: `sizeCheck n = quickCheckWith (stdArgs {maxSize = n})` (Introduction to Computation: Haskell, Logic and Automata; Sanella, Fourman, Peng, and Wadler; p. 272).

I do not see a way to combine `quickCheckAll` with `quickCheckWith`.

I tried using `$allProperties` (from the QuickCheck module) to collect the tests, then `map` over them with `quickCheckWith` (`runTests n = map (quickCheckWith (stdArgs {maxSize=n}) . snd) $allProperties`), but that did not work.

I suppose that I could use `arbitrary` to define test cases, but that seems to be going significantly out of the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my original question, I said,

> I do not see a way to combine quickCheckAll with quickCheckWith.

I was on the right track with here:

> I tried using $allProperties (from the QuickCheck module) to collect the tests, then map over them with quickCheckWith (runTests n = map (quickCheckWith (stdArgs {maxSize=n}) . snd) $allProperties), but that did not work.

I found what I was looking for reading the source code for the module `Test.QuickCheck.All`:

```
-- | Test all properties in the current module, using a custom
-- 'quickCheck' function. The same caveats as with 'quickCheckAll'
-- apply.
--
-- @$'forAllProperties'@ has type @('Property' -> 'IO' 'Result') -> 'IO' 'Bool'@.
-- An example invocation is @$'forAllProperties' 'quickCheckResult'@,
-- which does the same thing as @$'quickCheckAll'@.
--
-- 'forAllProperties' has the same issue with scoping as 'quickCheckAll':
-- see the note there about @return []@.
forAllProperties :: Q Exp -- :: (Property -> IO Result) -> IO Bool
forAllProperties = [| runQuickCheckAll |] `appE` allProperties
```

[gotta love that Haskell library source code is readily available like this <3]

Instead of `allProperties` and `quickCheckWith`, what I needed was `forAllProperties` and `quickCheckWithResult`.  With `forAllProperties` one need not manually `map` over the properties, as I tried to do.  The function, `quickCheckWithResult` is needed for outputting the results.

Thus,

```
runTests2 = $forAllProperties (quickCheckWithResult (stdArgs {maxSize = 9}))
```

is what I was looking for.

Comment: As @effectually advised in his answer, it would be better to have flexible size limits.  Here it would be ideal to have a size limit of ten on one test and a size limit of eight on the other.  I hardcoded the size limit as nine.  This is my first foray into TemplateHaskell, so I do not know, but I get a sense that the code `stdArgs {maxSize = 9}` could somehow by given as `stdArds {maxSize = n}' with 'n' being substituting during run time for values given with each test.  This is something to think about.

Answer (score 2):

Answering your question directly, you can use the

```hs
mapSize :: Testable prop => (Int -> Int) -> prop -> Property
```

function and set the size via, say, `mapSize (min 10)` like this:

```
prop_partitions :: Property
prop_partitions = mapSize (min 10) $ \n ->
  n >= 0 ==> all ((== n) . sum) (partitions n)
```

But it wouldn't be a good solution, because generally size should be adjustable, so that you can for example run compute-intensive tests overnight. So it would be better to use `` mapSize (`div` 10) `` or something of this sort (you probably don't want to generate `0` in 10% of cases, so you could make the logic fancier).

Note that you shouldn't introduce `cond ==> prop` unless you really have to, because throwing away generated cases is just wasted compute. And in your case it's trivial to avoid the conditional:

```hs
prop_partitions :: Property
prop_partitions = mapSize (`div` 10) $ \nPre ->
  let n = abs nPre
  in all ((== n) . sum) (partitions n)
```

Similarly for `prop_partitions'` you can use `map abs` to handle negative numbers and/or `` map (`rem` 10) `` to handle large numbers.

Comment: A proposal for one way to design the `Int -> Int` function to pass to `mapSize`: wikipedia gives [an approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#Partition_function) to the number of partitions, which you could invert. That way, asking for a test of size `n` would result in a test input which has about `n` possible partitions.

Comment: @DanielWagner great idea, thanks.

Comment: @effectfully:  Excellent advice about avoiding the conditional `cond ==> prop`.  I will keep that in mind in the future.  Right now, I am trying to adapt the tests as they are written in the textbook.  For the `Int -> Int` function you give to `mapSize`, did you mean `min` rather than `max`?  I think we want the lesser of two numbers there.

Comment: @effectfully:  you also make a good point about keeping the size limit flexible.  In the my answer to my own question, I hardcoded in the size limit.  This is adequate for my immediate purposes, but I would like to see how to make it flexible as you advise.

Comment: Oh yeah, you're right, I should've said `min` not `max`, thanks for catching, I'll edit the answer.